# Study the character of recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have tried yesterday to ask this question but probably it was not well written so I have decided to show you my attempt step by step.

I have to study the character of the following:
$$x_{n}=-x_{n-1}^2,\,\, x_1=x\in\mathbb{R}$$
First of all I have observed that for x=0 and x=-1 the sequence is constant so:

1. if $x=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, since $x_n=x_{n-1}$ iff $x_{n}=0,1$.
2. if $x=-1$. $x_1=-1,\, x_2=-1\,\,x_3=-1....x_n=-1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=-1$

Then $x_{n}-x_{n-1}=-x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}$. So:

1. if $-x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}>0$ then $-1<x_{n-1}<0$.
   Thus if $-1<x_1<0$ then $-1<x_n<0$ for each $n$. This means that the sequence is increasing and so it is convergent: $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=sup\{x_n\}=l$. $\textbf{l=0}$ since $x_n<0$.
2. if $-x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}<0$ then $x_{n-1}<-1\, \vee x_{n-1}>0$.
   Thus if $x_1<-1$ then $x_n<-1$ for each $n$: $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=inf\{x_n\}=l$. Since the possible finite limits are $0,-1$, they are not acceptable. So $\textbf{l=}$ $-\infty$.

Then?

Comment: It might be slightly simpler to consider the sequence $y_n = -x_n$, which satisfies the recursion $y_{n+1} = y_n^2$.

Comment: @MartinR sorry I have not understood...can you write me what you would do?

Comment: I have shown all my attempts but more than this I can't do...can you help me?

Comment: Note $x_m = -x^{2m}$.  Can you do that?  Hint 1: Ignore all this nonsense about negative values.  Solve it for a positive sequence and convert it to negatives later.  Hint 2: logarithms.

Comment: @fleablood no, $x_n = -x^{2^n}$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I agree

Comment: Anyone can say to me if I am right or there are some errors?

Comment: Please it is important for me. I have not found anyone that can say to me how the excercise has to be done...

Comment: What you write is right, but incomplete. See a solution below.

Comment: Oh, right $2^n$ but the idea is the same.  If $|x|>1$ then for any $K<0$ then if $n > \log_2 \log_{|x|} |K|$ then $|x|^{2^n} > |K|$ and $x_n < K$ so $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=-\infty$.   And if $|x|<1$ then $|x|^w$ is decreasing and for any $\epsilon >0$ if $n >\log_2\log_{|x|}\epsilon$ then $|x_n|=|x|^n < \epsilon$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

There is at least two methods.

Once you proved by recursion that $x^n = -x^{2^n}$, you deduce the limit $0$ if $|x|<1$, $-1$ if $|x|=1$, $-\infty$ if $|x|>1$.

Other method, which can work even when you have no close formula for $x_n$. First, make a picture showing the graph of $f : x \mapsto -x^2$ with the line of equation $y=x$, and showing graphically the first iterates. Then you see what happens, depending on the initial value.

Since $f : x \mapsto -x^2$ is continuous, if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges, the limit is a fixed point of $f$, i.e. $-1$ or $0$.

When $x=-1$ or $x=0$, the sequence $(x_n)$ is constant.

When $x<-1$, one has $f(x)<x$. The interval $]-\infty,-1[$ is stable under $f$. Hence a recursion shows that $x_n<-1$ for all $n$ and $(x_n)$ decreases. It has a limit $\ell \in [-\infty,-1[$ which can only be $-\infty$.

When $x>1$, one has $x_1<-1$, and you get the same conclusions but only for $n \ge 1$.

When $-1<x<0$, one has $x<f(x)<0$. The interval $]-1,0[$ is stable under $f$. Hence a recursion shows that $-1<x_n<0$ for all $n$ and $(x_n)$ increases. It has a limit $\ell \in ]-1,0]$ which can only be $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! So the soolution that states that for $|x|\geq 1$ the limit does not exhist is wrong? (for me an example in which limit that does not exhist  is (-1)^n)

Comment: Starting from a fixed point produces a constant sequence... Moreover, when $n \ge 1$, $2^n$ is even, so $-(-1)^{2^n}=-1$, even if wolfram does not notice that.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you